# KivyMD MDTabs can't handle

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm just started to work with KivyMD. I was working on MDTabs system. I'm trying to switch tab after release button. If I try **get_tab_list()** func. under MDTabs(id:tabs), I get this error:

> **AttributeError: 'MDTabs' object has no attribute 'get_tab_list'**

I can't figure it out. Please help me.

````
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDToolbar:
        title: "Example Tabs"
    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        default_tab: 2
        Tab:
            text: '1'
            Button:
                text: 'Go Tab 3'
                on_release: app.test()
        Tab:
            text: '2'
        Tab:
            text: '3'
'''
class Tab(MDTabsBase,FloatLayout):
    pass
class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    def test(self,*args):
        print('HELP :)')
Example().run()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall library from master branch - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD

Comment: Removed and reinstalled.Nothing changed.My version is:0.104.1. Is that code working on your system ?

Comment: I'm using linux and uninstalled kivymd like that: **python3 -m pip uninstall kivymd**. After that i installed like that: **python3 -m pip install kivymd==0.104.1**. Is there any way to reinstall ? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Reinstall library **from master branch** - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD

Comment: Ahh my bad. Thanks for answering mate. master branch solved my problem.