# KivyMD, can't see icons in android but works on linux

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I'm just created .apk file with buildozer.But as i said in topic, can't see any icon on device.Everything works and looks fine in Linux. But in device,all icons are blank. This is my buildozer.init requirements: *(my ndk,sdk,minapi,ndk_api values are default)*

> requirements = python3,kivy==1.11.1,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

If i use **kivymd==0.104.1**, i can see icons in android but can't use some commands like : **MDTab.get_tab_list() , MDTab.switch_tab()** (I asked that problem before [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364579/kivymd-mdtabs-cant-handle).So i have to use master branch version because i need to switch MDTabs after some button clicks.But now,i can't see any icon.Is that bug or can someone help me ? Thank you.. 
*(Last note: Im removing .buildozer file before change requirements versions.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set correct dependencies in buildozer.spec- https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/commit/df73810cc725e4575c93bc4cbbb72f67ff568dc1

Comment: Are you my MDAngel :) Thanks for answering and solutions mate. 3/3 worked and fixed my bugs..