# KivyMD MDFileManager shows only image files, how to list all file types?

Tags: python, kivy, file-manager, kivymd

I am developing a KivyMD text file explorer for Android. Following is the code snippet:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
            select_path=self.select_path,
            previous=False,
        )
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Permission.INTERNET])
self.ROOT_PATH = primary_external_storage_path()
```

Above initialization works flawlessly, also the following code statement launches the file manager/explorer.

```
self.file_manager.show(self.ROOT_PATH)
```

But the resulting contents are only either folder names or image files(.jpg, .jpeg, .png). No other file types are shown.

I tried following before invoking `self.file_manager.show(self.ROOT_PATH)`, but no change in response.

```
self.file_manager.use_access = True
self.file_manager.previous=False
self.file_manager.preview=False
```

When I tried `self.file_manager.ext = ['txt']` extension filtering technique, even the image files listing disappeared, only folder names were listed/shown.

Hence, I write this request seeking expert response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update library from master branch - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD, not from pip.
2. 

```
self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
    exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
    select_path=self.select_path,
    preview=True,
    # preview=True - deprecated
 )
```

3. If you set the "preview" parameter, then only images will be displayed in the file manager. If you want the file manager to display all file types do not use the "preview" paramete
4. 

```
self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
    exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
    select_path=self.select_path,
    ext=[".py", "kv"],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick support. It worked after updating, but is configuration of `ext` property mandatory? If so is there a way to specify all file extensions at once. Also button icons disappeared, probably MDIcon name has changed in the new release, will try to figure out the fix. Thanks and Regards!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63368152/kivymd-cant-see-icons-in-android-but-works-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

If the above case won't work, please try:

```py
self.file_manager = MDFileManager(exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
                                     select_path=self.select_path,)
   self.file_manager.ext = [".py",".kv"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue like you.

Found out on android.developers that actually for "All files" is needed the permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Just put in buildozer.spec file MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE also:

## (list) Permissions

android.permissions = INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
No need to put it in the py code as you mnetioned for the other other permissions.
they are ok in the code to avoit asking for the permission every time the app is launched.

But, after the app is installed you'll have to go on the app permission to all the management of all files [allow permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EyQk.jpg)

Worked for me, hope it helps.