# problem with MDIcon using Buildozer for android package

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I'm using kivyMD for my  mobile application and i've used buildozer for my android package.
my problem is that I have an MDIcon that's not displayed in my mobile but working fine when I test it in the IDE.
here is the part of my kv file where I have the icon:

```
       MDIcon:
           icon:'head-question'
           halign:'center'
           color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
           font_size : 48
           pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.82}
```

all the others kivy or kivymd widgets are working fine so what could be the cause?

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63368152/kivymd-cant-see-icons-in-android-but-works-on-linux/63368444#63368444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set correct dependencies in `buildozer.spec` - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/commit/df73810cc725e4575c93bc4cbbb72f67ff568dc1

`requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc3, git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git, sdl2_ttf==2.0.15`

Comment: thanks, it's working but it doesn't have the same size, the icon in the mobile app is smaller